How to add local file in bazel's pkg_tar?
I'm using bazel 5.4.1.
Despite searching diligently, I couldn't find the answer. I know new_local_repository can load local file into bazel project, but I do not find an direct and elegant method to make it into pkg_tar.
Any advise?

Assuming you have a directory that contains file data.bin that you want to package.
You probably added it to your WORKSPACE as:
new_local_repository(
    name = "local_file",
    path = "<path to your repository>/",
    build_file_content = """
exports_files(
    ["data.bin"],
)
""",
)

Then you can just refer it in your pkg_tar rule in a BUILD.bazel file:
load("@rules_pkg//pkg:tar.bzl", "pkg_tar")


pkg_tar(
    name = "sample_pkg",
    srcs = [
        "@local_file//:data.bin",
    ],
)

If you want to rename or place the file at specific path in the archive, you may need to pkg_files before that.

Does not work. I get the following error. Label '@rules_pkg//pkg:tar.bzl' is invalid because 'pkg' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@rules_pkg//:pkg/tar.bzl'?
